# Using the AWS AppConfigDataClient to fetch configuration data from the extension's localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-app-config

I am using the AWS AppConfigDataClient (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/appconfigdata/) to fetch configuration data.
There is also an AppConfig layer I have added to my lambda that makes the data available from localhost (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-integration-lambda-extensions.html).

Now, I was wondering if there is a way to use the AppConfigDataClient sdks to fetch the configuration data from the extension layer's localhost instead of fetching them remotely.